# mouse.displace is unpredictable

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, sprite, p5.js

I'm coding something with the play library in p5.js. On the screen there will be some images on the right side and when you click on one of them, the coloured version of the image appears on the screen. You can move it around by pushing it with your mouse. However, when I click on a second image and a second "movable" image appears, it's sometimes movable but most of the time it's not. I was wondering if it's because of my code or something else.

As you can see in the code I've tried displacing them individually but then it gives the error  "Uncaught Error: overlap can only be checked between sprites or groups". Which I first through was because of the var, but movingBlocks is also defined as a var at the beginning of the sketch so I don't understand. I would be very happy if someone can help me, thank you!

```
var movingBlocks;
var mouseBlock;
var bb1;
var b1;
var bb2;
var b2;
var b3;
var bb3;
var b4;
var bb4;
var b5;
var bb5;
var b6;
var bb6;
var b7;
var bb7;

function preload() {
  mouseBlock = loadImage('mouse.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  mouseBlock = createSprite(200,200);
  mouseBlock.addAnimation('normal', 'mouse.png');

  movingBlocks = new Group()
  var b1 = createSprite(windowWidth-100,75);
  b1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black01.png');
  b1.scale = 0.4;

  b1.onMousePressed= function() {
    var bb1 = createSprite(windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2);
    bb1.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp1.png');
    // tint(255,127);
    bb1.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb1);

  }

  var b2 = createSprite(windowWidth-100,200);
  b2.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black02.png');
  b2.scale = 0.4;

  b2.onMousePressed= function(){
    var bb2 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb2.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp2.png');
    bb2.scale = 0.3;
    movingBlocks.add(bb2);
  }

  var b3 = createSprite(windowWidth-100, 325);
  b3.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black03.png');
  b3.scale = 0.4;

  b3.onMousePressed = function(){
    var bb3 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb3.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp3.png');
    bb3.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb3);
  }

  var b4 = createSprite(windowWidth-100, 450);
  b4.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black04.png');
  b4.scale = 0.4;

  b4.onMousePressed = function(){
    var bb4 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb4.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp4.png');
    bb4.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb4);
  }

  var b5 = createSprite(windowWidth-100, 575);
  b5.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black05.png');
  b5.scale = 0.4;

  b5.onMousePressed = function(){
    var bb5 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb5.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp5.png');
    bb5.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb5);
  }

  var b6 = createSprite(windowWidth-100, 690);
  b6.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black06.png');
  b6.scale = 0.4;

  b6.onMousePressed = function(){
    var bb6 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb6.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp6.png');
    bb6.scale = 0.4;
    movingBlocks.add(bb6);
  }

  var b7 = createSprite(windowWidth-100, 825);
  b7.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/black/black07.png');
  b7.scale = 0.4;

  b7.onMousePressed = function(){
    var bb7 = createSprite(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    bb7.addAnimation('normal', 'stamps/gradient/Stamp7.png');
    bb7.scale = 0.5;
    movingBlocks.add(bb7);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(240,240,240);
  mouseBlock.position.x = mouseX;
  mouseBlock.position.y = mouseY;
  mouseBlock.scale=0.3;

        if(keyDown('x')) {
          bb1.rotation -= 6;
          // bb1.changeAnimation('spinning');
        }
  mouseBlock.displace(movingBlocks);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb1);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb2);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb3);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb4);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb5);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb6);
  // mouseBlock.displace(bb7);

  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: To make this more readable, you might consider putting all the 'b's and 'bb's into arrays. One thing that I noticed is that you're re-declaring all the `b`s and `bb`s in setup, which might lead to unpredictable behavior. It's only necessary to put `var` once for any variable.

Comment: @jstl thanks for leaving an answer! I tried this (I was dumb to oversee this) but sadly it didn't help. Could file size also be a problem? Because there are so many images. I still want to keep them a good quality because my aim is to export the animations and use them in video editing (this works). Now my files are around 152KB

Comment: I wouldn't expect the file sizes to be an issue. If you give the link of the editor, I might be able to help more.

Comment: If you suspect file size to be an issue, you can also try replacing your current images with smaller ones and see if the problem resolves itself.

Comment: @jstl thank you for your help! I had a very busy week so sorry for replying this late, but I tried moving around different things before asking for your help again. And in the end I just had to switch two lines around. But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer! It was so simple...
I just had to switch these two lines around:

```
mouseblock.displace(movingblocks);
drawSprites();
```

I'm not completely sure if this will always fix this issue, but I can move around all blocks so at least I have a final work to show at my presentation. Thanks for the help though!